# How to put labels in the input fields in the customer address edit?

Tags: customer-account, customer-address, labels

In **Magento 2.x**, on the **customer account** screen, I need to add labels to the **address inputs**. What is the best way to do this?

I was able to perform the same modification on the address inputs of the checkout screen, but I did not find anything for the address inputs on the customer account screen.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean labels to the address inputs? do you mean a placeholder?

Comment: They can be labels or placeholders. I would like to make clear to users the reference of each input. Can you help me?

Comment: could you post your codes of modification of the address inputs

Comment: did you use layoutprocessor?

Comment: have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add label using below code just above input field.

```
        <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
```

Comment: In what path and file inside the magento structure can I add this tag? The screen shown is the customer account, what file should I change to be able to add this label to the screen?